# C: fseek() not pointing to the defined Byte number

Tags: c, file, ip, forward, fseek

**SOLUTION AT BOTTOM**

I'm working on an IP forwarding program. After reading one header field, I use `fseek()` to point the file pointer to the beginning of the next IP header field. Only, I have a current position value of 20 and an offset of 40, yet when I `fseek()` it stays at Byte number 20.

```
struct line {
  unsigned char a; 
  unsigned char b;
  unsigned char c;
  unsigned char d;
};

struct line l1;

long datagram_length = 0;
int current_position = 0;
ip_packets = fopen("ip_packets", "r+");

fread(&l1, 4, 1, ip_packets);
header_length = l1.a & 0x0f;
header_length *= 4;
printf("Header length = %u\n", header_length);

datagram_length = l1.c * 256 + l1.d;
printf("Datagram length = %d\n", datagram_length);
printf("Current position = %d\n", current_position);
current_position += header_length;

fseek(ip_packets, datagram_length, current_position);
current_position += datagram_length;
printf("Current position = %d\n", current_position);

long pos;
pos = ftell(ip_packets);
printf("pos is %ld bytes\n", pos);
```

This prints:

```
Header length = 20
Datagram length = 40
Current position = 20
Current position = 60
pos is 20 bytes
```

The code above includes my variable initializations for the `fseek()` function. I have tried using `SEEK_CUR` as the `int whence` parameter, but then the program doesn't terminate. The end of file is never reached, after running for just a second I get `pos is 234167456 bytes` and the file is only 377 Bytes.

**UPDATE**

Apparently you are supposed to open the file in `r+` mode, so I have updated that, but it is still doing the same thing

```
ip_packets = fopen("ip_packets", "r+");
```

Also tried `rb` mode

**SOLUTION**

My solution was to just loop the number of bytes times and call `fgetc()` inside each loop. Not a good fit, but it works

Answer (score 1):

What is definition of your variable `current_position`?

Your usage of fseek seems wrong.  The man page for `fseek(3)` says the definition is:

`fseek(FILE *stream, long offset, int whence);`

For your use case, `whence` must be set to a constant `SEEK_CUR` defined in `stdio.h`.

Comment: I forgot to include variable initializations -- they have been added. I thought I was supposed to use `SEEK_CUR` as well, but then the file never reaches the end. I let it run for a second and the got `pos is 234167456 bytes` and the file is only 377 Bytes. The program doesn't terminate

Comment: It's not unusual that after fixing one bug you encounter another one.